# passing SQL Datatable to pre-designed Word table in Word template doc

Tags: .net, vb.net, templates, ms-word

Thank you for taking the time to read this problem and ponder a solution.

I have a Word Template (.dotx) which contains a pre-defined and styled table with two rows. The first is the header and the second is empty. It has five columns. The first cell in the first data row (not header) is bookmarked as 'Start'.

I have a datatable from SQL where all data returned is a string. There are five columns of data returned and the numbers of rows can vary but would always be less than 20

I can create a new table in the word document but I don't want that.

What I'd like to do is pass the data to the word table and for the number of rows in the word table to increase dynamically as required.

I can't find any references to identifying a particular table within an existing word document and passing data to it

I have managed to CREATE a table beneath the pre-existing one in the template but that's not what I want as I've the table already designed

```
'in the btn_click event
oDT = returnDataTable(sSQL) 'oDT is defined as a DataTable
Dim iFields As Integer = oDT.Columns.Count - 1
Dim sText As String = ""
For Each oRow As DataRow In oDT.Rows
    For idx = 0 To iFields
        sText += oRow.Item(idx)
        If idx < iFields Then sText += vbTab
    Next
Next

' then :

Private Function writeToWordByRange(ByVal sText As String) As Boolean
    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document
    wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    oDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles), "PathToDocTemplate.dotx"))
    wdApp.Visible = True
    ' the next four lines are from Stackoverflow
    Dim rng As Word.Range = oDoc.Content
    rng.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)
    rng.Text = sText
    Dim tbl As Word.Table = rng.ConvertToTable(vbTab)
    ' I added this line to see if I could pass the string to the table
    ' but it doesn't seem to take the vbTab as a delimiter but puts all the data into the first cell
    oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("Start").Range.Text = sText
    'release Word and continue
    oDoc = Nothing
    wdApp = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to start with a table that has only the header row. Put the bookmark in the paragraph immediately after the table.

Inserting the text below the table then converting it to a table will automatically merge the two tables, essentially appending the converted text to the table.

Note that in my testing, the columns of the original table and the appended content did not align exactly. If that turns out to be the case for you, also, this worked for me:

Insert the delimited text content somewhere else in the document and convert it to a table. Now copy or cut the table and paste it to the bookmark.

The relevant snippet from my test code:

```
Set tbl = oDoc.Tables(ActiveDocument.Tables.Count)
Set rng = oDoc.content
Set rngBookmark = oDoc.Bookmarks("Start").Range
rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
rng.Text = sText
Set tblNew = rng.ConvertToTable(Separator:=vbTab)
tblNew.Range.Cut
rngBookmark.PasteAppendTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You're a Master, a Saviour and an Angel!!

With minor modification it worked. I think you did it through VBA? Full credit to you. I am very grateful.

The working code is as follows:

```
Dim oT As Word.Table = oDoc.Tables(wdApp.ActiveDocument.Tables.Count)
Dim oRange As Word.Range = oDoc.Content
Dim bookMark As Word.Bookmark = oDoc.Bookmarks("Start")
oRange.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)
oRange.Text = sText
Dim newT As Word.Table = oRange.ConvertToTable(Separator:=vbTab)
newT.Range.Cut()
bookMark.Range.PasteAppendTable()
```